# Problem with margin in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin

I am having a problem with IE. The url to my site is www.trecall.com. I want to put a margin on the left side of the animated menu, to make the menu centered on the page. This works fine in FF, but in IE, the margin does not show up.

Any idea why?

THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping it in another div and using padding on that. IE is not very good with margins.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with left margin is not the correct way to do horizontal centering, it'll only work on your own display resolution..

see [this for horizontal centering in css](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html) (old but still correct)

Comment: ben,Thanks for your response. But I tried first doing margin:0 auto;- which did not work in any browsers. Then I tried doing what the article stated- text-align:center, which also did not show up in any browsers! Do you have any idea why it isn't working? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` is generally the correct way to do centering. However it only works for elements which have a defined `width` property. And `width` can't be defined for elements which are `display:inline`. If you want to center an inline element, you need to specify `text-align:center;` on its parent element.

Comment: spudley, the element I was trying to do margin:0 auto for has a defined width, and I believe it's not display:inline. Why wouldn't it work then? Any suggestions? Thanks, guys.

Comment: you have too many elements with margin/width/whatnot applied to. Start with an empty container, center it properly, then start adding your elements inside again..

Comment: okay, the menu is now centered on FF. But for some reason, on IE, it just stays in the same place-on the left side of the browser- no matter what! Why is that?

Comment: See my original reference. IE is dumb and works differently. On IE, the container (the element wrapping the one with margin:0 auto) should have text-align:center

Comment: for some reason, margin:0 auto does not work on the menu. (Even in FF). It shows up as no margin at all. ???

Comment: It's interesting- I added <div align="center> under the body tag in my html. This centered the site for all screen sizes, however the menu did NOT center; it stays in the same place!! Can something be wrong with my code?

Comment: align="center" is a bit old school these days. My advise would be trim down your css & html code to just a centered section like in the example and start adding bit and pieces again progressively